# SCons if/then statement

Tags: python, json, scons

I have a single SConscript file in a top level directory and I have many subdirectories with JSON files containing different key/value pair.  I have one `env.Command()` in my SConscript file that I want to be called based on the value of a particular key.  What is the best way to do this in Scons?

I was thinking something like:

```
env.Command(
    test = Value(params['json_key'])
    if test == "True":
        target = out.txt,
        source = in.txt,
        action = 'function $SOURCE $TARGET'
    else:
        pass
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Python, you cannot put an if/else inside something else like that.  However, you can pass arguments to `env.Command` using a dictionary.

```
if Value(params['json_key']) == "True":
    kw = {
        'target': 'out.txt',
        'source': 'in.txt',
        'action': 'function $SOURCE $TARGET',
    }
else:
    kw = {}
env.Command(**kw)
```